# Why does .delay break this short piece of code using Combine framework in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sequence, combine

Swift 5.x iOS 14

Wrote this code, trying understand the sequence publisher in the Combine Framework.

```
struct SwiftUIViewH: View {
  @State var textColor = Color.black
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
      .foregroundColor(textColor)
      .onAppear { 
        let initialSequence = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.orange]
        _ = initialSequence.publisher
              .delay(for: 1.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
              .sink {
                textColor = $0
                print($0)
              }
        }
  }
}
```

It works, in that I goes thru the list in milli-seconds and changes the colour of hello World if I don't try and slow the process down with a delay? But with delay in place as you see here, it does nothing it seems... **the code above is broken**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you do not store `Cancellable` returned after subscription. As soon as `Cancellable` is deallocated the whole subscription is cancelled.
Without delay everything works because subscriber is called immediatly, right after subscription.

Add property to your view:

```
@State var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
```

And save `Cancellable` returned after subscription:

```
cancellable = initialSequence.publisher
```

However your code won't add delay **between** each color change. All colors are sent immediatly -> you add delay to each event -> after 1 sec all colors are sent to subscriber :) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/667482/murlakatam Thanks for your answer. I checked it off as the accepted one since it does indeed fix the code, even if I still just get an orange word and miss all the others.

Comment: @user3069232 If you need this only to test something, then replace `.delay(for: 1.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)` with `.zip(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default).autoconnect())` and color will change after each second.